# WPF Swipe feature for grid in ItemControl

Tags: wpf, datagrid, swipe

I am looking for swipe feature for grid dynamic items to enable delete and edit functionality, SO if user swipe a grid row to left, delete button will show and if he swipe to right edit button will show.

Is there any thing available for this in WPF which fit best for Grid in ItemControl?

I am trying simple manipulation, but by clicking mouse on it to move its not working
My development machine is hp laptop windows 10

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-creating-your-first-touch-application

Comment: I think you will need to add some more details of what you have tried so far; researched, etc., before you are likely to get a good response here.

Comment: There is one library I find out so far but that is not free and other than that I have found xamrin swipe grids which cannot be used. So that is why I have posted the question here